# How can I deploy a global value set?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, deployment-error

I am trying to deploy via Metadata API a global value set that is already existing in production. But I keep hitting an error stating:

**Error  Region fullName must end with: __gvs**

Region is the picklist name

Now, this global picklist was previously deployed a month ago with no issues. But suddenly the same picklist is now throwing this error.

I have even tried changing the name to include __gvs, and this did not work either.

Can someone let me know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using API version 56.0. You have to append __gvs in the package XML. It is [documented](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_api_global_value_set_suffix.htm&type=5&release=240) here.

*Before 56.0*

```
<members>gvs1</members>
```

*After 56.0*

```
<members>gvs1__gvs</members>
```

Also check the Actual file (metadata file) names in the package folder. You may need to rename the files as well by appending `__gvs` at the end of the filename before extension name.

*File Name Before 56.0*

```
<global Value Set API Name>.globalValueSet
```

*File Name After 56.0*

```
<global Value Set API Name>__gvs.globalValueSet
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This looks relevant.

Comment: As far as I can tell this change was pulled from v56 before release.
I'm having problems pushing updates via v56 but I'm able to push updates as normal via v57 (Sprint '23) without the `__gvs` suffix.